# How to delete embedded resource in c#?

Tags: c#

I have an exe file that contains an embedded (source) video. After running a program, i have to copy it somewhere in order to run it. So that video will be twice on disc. That's why I would like to remove the video from exe after the extracting.

Comment: I think you can only modify embedded resources at compile time.  Can you load the embedded video into a memory stream and play it that way?

Comment: Why not just extract the video on a temp folder and delete it afterwards? Or just distribute the video as a normal external file instead of embedding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not. Simply speaking - the video should not be a resource to start with. Per general WINDOWS rules (nothing .NET) a program should never make ANY modifications to the install folder - normal users have no writing rights there. Any resource should be installed by an INSTALLER.

You totally violate any decent rule about how to handle resources. Fix that - then you do not have he even more violating idea that a program should rewrite it's own code.

Comment: Oh, so I should make an installer (msi), and it extracts the exe and the video too, and the exe would point to the video?

Comment: Exactly. Like any other application does it.